# which is the best proof to use for gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, b − a)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove that gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, b − a)

What is the best way to prove this? using induction? or does there exist a more efficient method?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1206170/242) for the essence of the matter.

Answer (score 6):

The shortest method consists in proving a more general fact:
$$\{\text{divisors of }a \text{ and }b\}=\{\text{divisors of }a \text{ and }b-a\}$$

Comment: did you mean b-a?

Comment: Yes, but it's the same anyway.